# How do i remove a specific term in my dataframe string?

Tags: r, word-frequency

```
   df <- dataframe$Data %>%
      na.omit() %>%
      tolower() %>%
      strsplit(split = " ") %>% 
      unlist() %>%
      table() %>%
      sort(decreasing = TRUE)
```

Hey guys, im using these functions to get a list of word frequency (im working with a giant text), but im getting repeated words like "banana" , "banana.", "banana?" etc. and they are counting separately. How do i delete the dots, interrogation and others to sum banana correctly? Thx!!!

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using :

```
df <- dataframe$Data %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  tolower() %>%
  strsplit(split = " ") %>% 
  unlist() %>%
  gsub('[[:punct:]]', '', .) %>%
  table() %>%
  sort(decreasing = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you!!! It worked. And what if i want, now, to just let specific punctuation appear? E.g: # and @.

Comment: You could specify all the punctuations to be removed in `gsub` ie. `gsub('[.?]', '', .)`